# default timezone in PHP

Tags: php

What is default timezone in php? I checked it in the php.ini which shows the following with the timezone is left blank:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
;date.timezone =

;date.default_latitude = 31.7667
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333
```

Then I want to know which timezone is used by default while manipulating times in PHP if I don't set it explicitly by using date_deafult_timezone_set() or any other means ?

Comment: The default timezone in PHP is the default for your server.

Comment: Duplicate of the fine manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Comment: Then what is this default if it isn't shown in the php.ini file as shown in my question ? @Radix

Comment: Don't set it in php.ini, execute a script with date functions and warnings enabled, and the warning will tell you

Comment: in WAMP default date.timezone = UTC

Comment: @ZahidulHosseinRipon thanks for the answer. I am actually using WAMP, so it is using UTC,despite the fact that it does not show date.timezone = UTC in the php.ini file,right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Rosemary. Since you are using WAMP, do you have access to your machine's root? If so, you can set the machine time as you per your operating system specific instructions.

Comment: The warning issued when `date.timezone` is not set:  "_Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone._"  <-- so UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not specified date.timezone defaults to the system environment variable TZ.
You can use this code to check your default value `date_default_timezone_get()`.

Further info can be found here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Comment: Note that the TZ environment variable is **not** being read by PHP 5.4.0 and higher. You should set `date.timezone` in your php.ini instead.

Comment: This is no longer true. UTC is the default after 5.4.0.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP 7 Answer

Modern versions of PHP (>= 5.4.0) use the following steps until a default timezone is found:

1. Reading the timezone set using the date_default_timezone_set() function (if any)
2. Reading the value of the date.timezone ini option (if set)
3. If none of the above succeed, the default timezone will be UTC.

The `TZ` environment variable is no longer used.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for me on Debian 11 with php 7.4.28. No timezone is set in the .ini files. `grep -r 'date.timezone' /etc/php/` shows all files have the setting undefined and commented out. But `date_default_timezone_get()` and the "Default timezone" in `phpinfo();` show the correct timezone.

Answer (score 2):

A simple code you have to write for the default timezone. which is:

```
date_default_timezone_get()
```

Now how to use:

You have to pass the timezone in this function like we want to set India timezone as default see:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
```

Now, whenever you would use date(), automatically return India timezone.

I would refer if you want a example: [how to convert default date timezone in php](http://asktofolks.com/598/how-to-convert-default-date-timezone-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can check from the experiment everything that is described below:

if php\php-fpm have date.timezone setting in config then  default timezone
will be equal date.timezone

if php\php-fpm dont have date.timezone in their config then php\php-fpm
try to find out timezone of the host. if they succeed then default timezone
will be equal host time zone. if they dont succeed ( the example pls have a look below) then default time zone will be equal UTC.

examples.

host time zone:

```
# stat /etc/localtime 
  File: /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Helsinki
```

php\php-fpm timezone

```
# php -i | grep timezone
Default timezone => Europe/Helsinki
date.timezone => no value => no value

# php-fpm7.3   -i | grep timezone
Default timezone => Europe/Helsinki
date.timezone => no value => no value
```

so php\php-fpm successfully determined host timezone

next example

host timezone:

```
# stat /etc/localtime 
   File: /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Antarctica/Casey
```

php\php-fpm timezone

```
# php -i | grep timezone
Default timezone => UTC
date.timezone => no value => no value

# php-fpm7.3   -i | grep timezone
Default timezone => UTC
date.timezone => no value => no value
```

php\php-fpm couldnt identify host timezone and set UTC timezone

next example.
host timezone:

```
# timedatectl 
               Local time: Wed 2023-06-21 00:22:59 CEST
           Universal time: Tue 2023-06-20 22:22:59 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Budapest (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

we set date.timezone in config files

```
php cli config
# cat /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini |  grep timezone | grep -v ";"
date.timezone = "Antarctica/Casey"

 php-fpm config
# cat /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini|  grep timezone | grep -v ";"
date.timezone = "Antarctica/Casey"
```

check php\php-fpm timezone

```
# php -i | grep timezone
Default timezone => Antarctica/Casey
date.timezone => Antarctica/Casey => Antarctica/Casey


# php-fpm7.3   -i | grep timezone
Default timezone => Antarctica/Casey
date.timezone => Antarctica/Casey => Antarctica/Casey
```

so when date.timezone is set php\php-fpm dont care about host timezone

Answer (score -1):

```
;date.timezone =
; This is diasable text
This is working text
```

Get it? with this **;** On some ini files you can disable some scripts/codes.
You can set your time zone in php like:
    `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` And other like Europe/Amsterdam...
Read more on [php default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)